# How to replace agrep with something faster?

Tags: string, grep, match

I am currently using approximate grep (Agrep) to get matches between a list of thousands of short strings vs. a list of millions of longer strings.

Task:

find 'ABCD' in 'ABCDE', '...XYZABCDEFG...' or even '...XYZqBCDEFG...' (1 mismatch)

agrep works fine, but it's too slow for what I have to do (string matching with 1 mismatch). Can anybody recommend a faster alternative?

Comment: You'll need to be more explicit about what you "have to do".

Comment: updated with an example

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how the performance of this answer will compare to what you have now.

start with

```
one_mismatch_regex() {
    local patterns
    for ((i=0; i < ${#1}; i++)); do
        patterns+=( "${1:0:i}.${1:i+1}" )
    done
    local IFS='|'
    echo "${patterns[*]}"
}
```

That does this:

```
$ one_mismatch_regex foobar
.oobar|f.obar|fo.bar|foo.ar|foob.r|fooba.
```

So:

```
while read search_word; do
    one_mismatch_regex "$search_word"
done < searches.txt |
grep -E -f - data.txt
```

The while loop will transform the list of search words into a regex that will match the word with one mismatch, and write the regexes to stdout. Then, grep will use extended regex matching (`-E`) and read the regexes from the file named `-` (stdin).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It looks like taking the same time:

17:08:58.450521007 +0100 end_regex.txt
17:08:20.494522421 +0100 start_regex.txt
17:07:14.418524883 +0100 end_agrep.txt
17:06:39.930526168 +0100 start_agrep.txt

35 seconds for agrep, 38 for regex